# convert/match between DT_WSTR and DT_I8

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a column on my database as DT_I8 (bigint. I am using google analytics template to retreive some data and corresponding column for that column is DT_WSTR. I have to use look up tool to join them but it will not allow me. how can I convert one of them to other? I tried to convert it to bigint with conversion tool by using following (DT_I8)myColumn. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry I fixed my tipo. I meant DT_WSTR

Comment: Can you just cast the string as bigint in the query where you are doing the look-up?

Comment: It is number bigger than int max size. therefore I defined as bigint. Data is coming from google adwords.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are some non-numeric values in DT_WSTR data type column, the conversion (DT_I8)myColumn would be failed.

To convert DT_I8 to DT_WSTR data type in ssis, we can use Data Conversion Component or Derived Column Component.

UniCode string [DT_WSTR] as Data type for mycolumn in Data Conversion Component.

(DT_WSTR,1000) mycolumn as Expression in Derived Column Component.

Comment: I tried with  Derived Column Component but no chance. It doesnt convert at all for me. Same thing I tried converting a string into date which has format like 20140119 using this command (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(Ct_date,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Ct_date,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Ct_date,7,2)), although it reformats it as 2014-01-19, it will not change the date type. why is it? I havent tried data conversion component yet.

Comment: I have just tried data conversion component and it works indeed.

Answer (score 1):

In your conversion shape there will be a column "Output Alias".

This is the name of a new column added to the data flow with the output of the conversion.

In the lookup task ensure you are joining the NEW column rather than old one. Then it will have the correct data type.

Comment: there are 2 tools indeed. Derived Column Transformation and Data conversion, which one do you mean?

Comment: data conversion component works but not Derived Column Transformation. then I am not sure what for is this Derived Column Transformation?